# Processing <img> Tags Through JavaScript Before Fully Loaded

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to process  tags before they're fully loaded on screen? I'm trying to make a Chrome Extension that changes the images of a Google Image Search. I have managed to do the replacing part of it, but the effect doesn't look as realistic because the original images load for a split second before getting replaced. Is there a way to force the  on Google Images to load through my JavaScript?

Note: The Content Script in my manifest.json is running the `"run_at": "document_end"` so it's running as quickly as it can *after* the DOM loads I believe.

Comment: how about having an overlay on the whole screen while you are processing images?

Comment: I'd add a gray overlay with opacity set to 50% and fill the existing images with the overlay as it's loading. Sort've how iOS updates existing apps on the iPhone.

Comment: @fuzz that might actually work. I'm worried about how "fake" it will look but that's definitely worth a try!

Comment: The question should include a more detailed description of the processing. In some cases it can be achieved via chrome.webRequest redirection inside the background page, in other cases MutationObserver inside a content script that runs on document_start, or maybe it can be solved via pure CSS.